# Binary search tree Searching troubleshooting

Tags: java, search, binary-search-tree

I've spent about two days pouring over this and I have no idea what's missing. Originally my *BST* used comparables, then I switched it to int to simplify it when it wasn't working.

I add several items to a tree and it successfully prints them out in order. Then, the first time I call the *search()* method it returns true, as it should. Every other search call after that returns false whether it is true or false.

I'm including most of my code here in case the problem isn't related with the search method itself.

The output SHOULD be: `4 12 23 27 30 42 60 84 true true false true true`

but instead I get: `4 12 23 27 30 42 60 84 true false false false false`

```
public class BSTree {

    TreeNode root;
    static int comparison;

    public void insert(int value) {
        if (root == null) {
            root = new TreeNode(value);
        }
        else {
            root.insert(value);
        }
    }

    public boolean search(int chicken) {
        if (root != null ) {
            return root.search(chicken);
        }

        return false;
    }
    public static int height(TreeNode b) {
        return TreeNode.height(b);
    }

    public static void CompareSet() {
         comparison++;
    }

    public int getCompare() {
        return comparison;
    }

    public void ResetCompare() {
        comparison = 0;
    }

    public static void traverseInOrder (TreeNode node) {
        if (node != null) {
            traverseInOrder(node.left);
            System.out.print(" " + node.data);
            traverseInOrder (node.right);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        BSTree tree = new BSTree();

        tree.insert(30);
        tree.insert(42);
        tree.insert(84);
        tree.insert(12);
        tree.insert(4);
        tree.insert(23);
        tree.insert(27);
        tree.insert(60);

        traverseInOrder(tree.root);
        System.out.println("\n" + tree.search(30));
        System.out.println("\n" + tree.search(4));
        System.out.println("" + tree.search(50));
        System.out.println("" + tree.search(27));
        System.out.println("" + tree.search(42));
        System.out.println(height(tree.root));

    }
}
```

Here is the *treeNode* class:

```
public class TreeNode<T> {

    int data;
    TreeNode left;
    TreeNode right;


    TreeNode(int value){
        this.data = value;
        //right = null;
        //left = null;
    }

    public void insert(int value) {
        if (value == data) {
            return;
        }

        if (value < data) {
            if (left == null) {
                left = new TreeNode(value);
            }
            else {
                left.insert(value);
            }
        }
        else {
            if (right == null) {
                right = new TreeNode(value);
        }
        else {
            right.insert(value);
        }
    }

    public boolean search(int value) {

        BSTree.CompareSet();

        if (data == value) return true;

        if (data < value && left!=null)
            return left.search(value);
        else if(data > value && right != null) 
            return right.search(value);
        return false;   
    }

    public static int height(TreeNode b) {
        if (b == null) return -1;
        return 1 + Math.max(height(b.left), height(b.right));
    }

    public int getData(){
        return data;
    }
    public TreeNode getLeftChild() {
        return left;
    }

    public void setLeftChild(TreeNode leftChild) {
        this.left = leftChild;
    }

    public TreeNode getRightChild() {
        return right;
    }

    public void setRightChild(TreeNode rightChild) {
        this.right = rightChild;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comparaisons are reversed :))) Here is the corrected TreeNode::search method :

```
public boolean search(int value) {

    BSTree.CompareSet();

    if (data == value) return true;

    if (data > value && left!=null)
        return left.search(value);
    else if(data < value && right != null) 
        return right.search(value);
    return false;   
}
```

I think you swapped the `data` and the `value` variables.

Answer (score 0):

just change your **search** method of TreeNode class to this:

```
public boolean search(int value) {

    Test.CompareSet();

    if (data == value) return true;

    if (data < value && right!=null)
        return right.search(value);
    else if(data > value && left != null) 
        return left.search(value);
    return false;   
}
```

When your current node's data is greater than value you need to go to left sub-tree. And when current node's data is smaller than value you need to go to right sub-tree. You just have done the reverse one.

Comment: Or simply reverse the comparaisons